# Does Blazor Web Assembly work with CSS variables in CSS Isolation files?

Tags: css, blazor-webassembly

Does CSS variables work in a Blazor component with CSS islolation files ?
When my component named Test.razor has no CSS isolation file and has the style set:

```
<h1 class="mh1">Test</h1>
<style>
    :root {
        --mblue:#0000ff;
    }

    .mh1{
        color:var(--mblue);
    }
</style>
```

Test is indeed blue.
However if I put the styles in a isolation file name Test.razor.css it does not work.

```
:root {
    --mblue: #0000ff;
}

.mh1 {
    color: var(--mblue);
}
```

The component Test resides in the index page:

```
@page "/"
<Test></Test>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is yes, but not so sure that you can use :root in a css isolation file (the class is no longer called :root in a css isolation file -- it gets a random suffix with css isolation).

My approach has been as follows:

1. Use a wrapper element to provide a context to assign the css variables to.
2. Then use the variable in the class you assign to the relevant element.

**Test.razor**

```
<div class="test-wrapper">
    <h1 class="mh1">Text</h1>
</div>
```

**Test.razor.css**

```
.test-wrapper {
    --mblue: #0000ff;
}

.mh1 {
    color: var(--mblue);
}
```

Comment: Having come from c# - Just getting to grips with CSS etc. I thought :root had some special significance. Thanks Neil.